# Summarizing data in SAS across groups

Tags: sas

My data set is in this format as mentioned below:

```
NEWID
Age
H_PERS
Income
OCCU
FAMTYPE
REGION
Metro(Yes/No)
Exp_alcohol
population sample-(This is the weighted population each new id represents) etc.
```

I would like to generate a summarized view like below:

```
average expenditure value (This should be sum of (exp_alcohol/population sample))

% of population sample across Region Metro and each demographic variable
```

Please help me with your ideas.

Comment: `Demographic variable` is a bit unclear from the info. you have supplied. Can we please see a sample data set or an expected output?

Comment: Questions asking for code must show a minimal understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see your data set and your description was not very clear, I'm going to guess that you have data that looks something like this and you would like add some new variables that summarizes your data...

```
data alcohol;
input NEWID Age H_PERS Income OCCU $ FAMTYPE $ REGION $ Metro $ 
Exp_alcohol population_sample;
datalines;
1234 32 4 65000 abc m CA Yes 2 4
5678 23 5 35000 xyz s WA Yes 3 6
9923 34 3 49000 def d OR No 3 9
8844 26 4 54000 gdp m CA No 1 5
;
run;

data summar;
    set alcohol;
    retain TotalAvg_expend metro_count total_pop;

    Divide = exp_alcohol/population_sample;
    TotalAvg_expend + Divide; 
    total_pop + population_sample;
    if metro = 'Yes' then metro_count + population_sample;
    percent_metro = (metro_count/total_pop)*100;
    drop NEWID Age H_PERS Income OCCU FAMTYPE REGION Divide;
run;
```

Output:

```
                  Exp_     population_    TotalAvg_    metro_    total_    percent_
       Metro    alcohol       sample        expend      count      pop       metro

        Yes        2            4          0.50000        4         4       100.000
        Yes        3            6          1.00000       10        10       100.000
        No         3            9          1.33333       10        19        52.632
        No         1            5          1.53333       10        24        41.667
```